# GNOME3/Shell Quick Music Access

Tags: linux, gnome3

After having been a Gnome user since initial release in 1999, I have now upgraded to Gnome3. I figured despite everyone's moaning, over 10 years of a successful desktop means I should give it a fair go.

One thing:

If I have a music player such as Rhythmbox open, how can I change track without breaking my current task focus and heading to "Activities" now that the notification area icon is no more? I change track alot, do I really want to change windows to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification icons should appear when you touch the bottom-right corner.

Alternatively, look for "media keys" on your keyboard.

Comment: Yea, the black bar appears, but nothing music related, just app messages. My sensible keyboard has no media keys ;) I'd hate to see a major function like that rely on them

Comment: Actually, it only shows the Rhythmbox icon when it is actually playing. So if you pause from the main window, it isn't there. Could be a bug *heads off to mailing lists*